# a simple implementation of java linkedlists

Tags: java

I was just trying to implement Java linked list in a simple adding and removing program, but I could not get the output. It says:

> Note: LinkedListDemo.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note:
>   Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

when I try to compile and run. This is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class LinkedListDemo {

   public static void main(String args[]) {

      LinkedList ll = new LinkedList();

      ll.add("F");
      ll.add("B");
      ll.add("D");
      ll.add("E");
      ll.add("C");
      ll.addLast("Z");
      ll.addFirst("A");
      ll.add(1, "A2");
      System.out.println("Original contents of ll: " + ll);


      ll.remove("F");
      ll.remove(2);
      System.out.println("Contents of ll after deletion: "
       + ll);


      ll.removeFirst();
      ll.removeLast();
      System.out.println("ll after deleting first and last: "
       + ll);


      Object val = ll.get(2);
      ll.set(2, (String) val + " Changed");
      System.out.println("ll after change: " + ll);
   }
}
```

Comment: So did you recompile with `-Xlint` as suggested? Note that you haven't *implemented* a linked list at all - you're just using the built-in one. You should read up on *generics* though. Basically, if you change your declaration to `LinkedList<String> ll = new LinkedList<String>();` I suspect you'll find life a lot better...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use LinkedList instead of LinkedList to avoid warnings

Comment: IT WORKS...! while I am using                                     LinkedList<String> ll = new LinkedList<String>();   instead of just saying  LinkedList ll = new LinkedList(); convinced. BUT again I have a doubt,we know that the main difference between linked list and array is array consists of same type of data whereas linked list can hold any type of data,then what is the point that Iam saying <Integer> or <String> ect. pls make it clear for me.